# Problem with importing deepface in python

Tags: python, python-module, deepface

I want to analyse pictures I've saved local in python using PyCharm. I found the module called `deepface` to do so. I've installed it via the windows prompt and use this code in my script:

```
from deepface import DeepFace

result = DeepFace.analyze(img_path='C:\\Users\\...\\UC0f4MuOdnBnWbk_YuCmjwKA.jpg', actions=['gender','age'])
print(result)
```

But everytime I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

I've checked tensorflow and it's installed...

I'm pretty new to python, so please be kind, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What tf version do you have? Try to have this: tensorflow==2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

So I've foudn out that deepface doesn't work with Python 3.11 because of different dependencies (Status from 2022/11/20). For me Python 3.8 worked.